# iMac gamma problem

Tags: imac

I have an iMac 24", running OSX 10.5.8. I noticed sometimes when I wake my Mac from screensaver, the gamma is off. The screen becomes very white-washed looking. I can get it back to normal gamma by firing up System Preferences -> Display without changing any settings.

I do this every time and it's become very annoying. Can someone tell me what's going on and how I can fix it permanently? I don't have this problem on my MBP.

Comment: For reference I had this same issue with my iMac - it was fixed with 10.6.

Comment: I believe there was a period when my MacBook Pro would also behave like this after sleep. I don't remember if I found any solution to this.

I've not had it with 10.6, though.

Perhaps it's time to think about upgrading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give [Flux](http://www.stereopsis.com/flux/) a try. It’s a “free” tiny application that not only will help you not burn your eyes when it’s “dark” outside, but also touches the gamma every time and perhaps when doing that it bypasses Leopard’s bug.

Comment: It's a complete non-starter if you care about colour accuracy.

Comment: True to a certain degree. The OP doesn’t mention color accuracy being a requested feature anyway. If you need to write or perform non-color related activities, I much rather have flux, but if you’re going to be messing with color profiles and need that, then you’re probably the group of people with a hardware calibrator :)